# Typescript ambient declaration with function as default export

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to shim the types for the express syntax for [locale](https://github.com/florrain/locale) in my project, but am unsure how to do it as it is a function as a default export, not an object.

Currently I have this which stops typescript from erroring but doesn't give me types:

```
declare module 'locale';
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
declare function locale(supported: string[], def: string): void;
```

What do I need to do? I can't find any useful documentation here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
declare module 'locale' {
  export default function locale(supported: string[], def: string): void;
}
```

Also: [official documentation on the topic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries)